# How do you get Tkinter to stop reading text at a specific character in python using .get()?

Tags: python, tkinter

How do you get Tkinter to stop reading text at a specific character in python using .get()?
I tried using

```
.get(1.0, "end-5c")
```

but it did not work because the text is always changing.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following at all here. You should show a minimal example of the code you have, and explain how you'd want it to behave.

Answer (score 1):

Use the text widget mark. See `mark_set`, `mark_names` and so on. This puts a mark in the text that will flow with the text.

```
text.mark_set('mymark', 2.2)
text.get(1.0, 'mymark')
```

The above would put a mark in on the second line after the second character and then get the text from the start to that mark. If you insert text between these commands, the mark position will move and can be read using `text.index('mymark')` if you need to know the actual index.